# WPF binding messes with my stream?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, stream

I've made a control with a property of type [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
The stream I feed it has it's [`CanWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canwrite%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [`CanRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to true and it is necessary.

While debugging I've noticed that right after I call `OnPropertyChanged` (which by its name is self-explanatory) those properties become false.

With some irrelevant code excluded it looks like this:

```
public Stream FileStream
{
    get { return _fileStream; }
    private set
    {
        _fileStream = value;

        // Can read and write (for both _fileStream and value).
        OnPropertyChanged();
        // Can NOT read and write anymore.
    }
}
```

Any idea what can cause this awkward behavior?
I'd show more code but I don't have any leads on this yet.

---

Still diagnosing and this is my call stack between from `OnPropertyChanged` to the getter of `FileStream`, it seems to access it:

```
'The getter in the code shown above'
[Native to Managed Transition]  
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(object, int) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(int) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.RawValue()  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(object, bool) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(bool)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(bool, bool, bool) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(int, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView, object, bool)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourcePropertyChanged(object, string) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnPropertyChanged(object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>.DeliverEvent(object, System.EventArgs, System.Type)    Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Unknown
'OnPropertyChanged'
```

I also thought maybe it updates the change, and a binding changes it again right to something bad, so I've set the mode to a `OneWay` on the stream's binding but that didn't help either.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Tell us how you diagnose this.

Comment: What is bound to the filestream?

Comment: @lll The same control is responsible to set the `FileStream` and it is binding it to another control's stream property.